# How can I know if url-encoded string is UTF-8 or Latin-1 with PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, url-encoding

I am getting data from various site through url. Url parameters are url-encoded with the php `urlencode()` function, but character encoding can be still be UTF-8 or Latin-1.

For example, the *é* character, when url-encoded from UTF-8 becomes %C3%A9 but when url-encoded from Latin-1, it becomes %E9.

When I get data through url, I use `urldecode()` and then I need to know what is the character encoding so I eventually use `utf8_encode` before I insert them in a MySQL database.

Strangely, the following code doesn't work :

```
$x1 = 'Cl%C3%A9ment';
$x2 = 'Cl%E9ment';

echo mb_detect_encoding(urldecode($x1)).' / '.mb_detect_encoding(urldecode($x2));
```

It returns  `UTF-8 / UTF-8`

Why is that, what am I doing wrong and how can I know the character encoding of those string ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using `$_GET` you should not use `urldecode()` as the values are already decoded.

Comment: @jeroen - Most likely, it's just a trick to create a simple test case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The example is clear, that's why it's just a comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mb_detect_encoding()` is normally useless with the default second parameter:

```
<?php

$x1 = 'Cl%C3%A9ment';
$x2 = 'Cl%E9ment';

$encoding_list = array('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1');

var_dump(
    mb_detect_encoding(urldecode($x1), $encoding_list),
    mb_detect_encoding(urldecode($x2), $encoding_list)
);
```

... prints:

```
string(5) "UTF-8"
string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: It's working, thanks ! Does that mean that I need to know in advance what the encoding could have been used ? Isn't there a simple way to detect any existing character encoding ?

Comment: It's a URL: it should be UTF-8 all the time, except in really legacy and misconfigured browsers where it can be ISO-8859-1. I don't think there're other possibilities. And no, there's no simple and reliable way to detect the encoding of a text among the hundreds of encodings that exist.