# Javascript automatically converts UTF to ISO-8859

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf

Im having really strange problem problem with encoding and it drives me crazy.

So lets assume this:

```
function Test(Name, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.php",
        data: "Name=" + Name,
        success: function (msg) {
            callback(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

and the test.php file:

```
function is_utf8($string) {
    return (mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', true) == 'UTF-8');
}

    if (is_utf8($_POST["Name"])){
        echo "Im in UTF";
    }
    else{
        echo "im not in UTF!!";
    }
```

**EDIT - Read this** 
I found something -> at [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp][http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp] I see that problem is causing the encoding so that e.g. "%21" becomes exclamation mark. How to stop this from happening? I want to simply pass %21 and in PHP get string "%21% string so when I convert it to UTF I get exclamation mark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know if url-encoded string is UTF-8 or Latin-1 with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384050/how-can-i-know-if-url-encoded-string-is-utf-8-or-latin-1-with-php)

Comment: I dont want to what charset it is... This question is about why it converts it. I know exactly what the input charset is.

Comment: jQuery will transform _data_ into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - see **processData** on [`.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). According to that same page it should still be UTF-8. Maybe try setting `processData: false`. Also the example on that page uses `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I found out that the problem is causing Url encoded string such as "%21%". I edited post accordingly, can you take a look please?

Comment: You probably just need to use [`urldecode`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: I thought something similar however urldecode didnt do the trick as it should - maybe because the string is not in utf?. I narrowed it down - I post "%Be" I want to get "%Be" also in php, however I always end up getting some rubbish unknown characters. Thank you very much for looking into this though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also if I use urlencode I get the "%Be" string in php, but then all other characters get encoded too which is not what I wanted... ./

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve here but jQuery does not understand the data argument that you have written. You need to use `data: { name: "the name you want to POST"} `

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use

```
encodeURIComponent(Name)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the your answer and put it into context of the question?  Thank you.